# How to tell if the Eclipse index is complete?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse-CDT 2019-06 on a large codebase.  Recently, the Call Hierarchy showed only a few of the callers of a function.  I suspect indexing was stopped for some reason and Eclipse silently left me with an incomplete index.  Assuming that's the case, how can I find out if indexing has been interrupted?

Initially the Call Hierarchy had 4 or 5 callers in it.  I rebuilt the index several times.  Each time I made sure to wait until the indexer was finished before doing anything.  I got a list of about 50 callers of the function each time.  It looked like the same list each time, although I have no way to be sure it was the complete list.  (I need to be able to count on the Eclipse indexer for that!)

Eclipse has options controlling when files are reindexed relative to editing.  I do not believe this was relevant.  In that session I had edited only one or two files, and the callers that were not found were from numerous other files that I have never touched.

According to [Eclipse indexing - what do the various options do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778429/eclipse-indexing-what-do-the-various-options-do), it is possible for indexing to be cancelled leaving the index incomplete.

The only explanation I have is that my index was incomplete the first time around.  Something I did - perhaps a build - cancelled indexing and left my index incomplete.  However Eclipse did not indicate in any way that anything was amiss.

Is this a reasonable and likely explanation?  If so, is there a way to find out if the index is complete?  What actions cause indexing to be cancelled?

Comment: Maybe try reindexing? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3008319/1913185